# Scanning webpage looking for broken 403/404 references (with flash support)

Tags: c#, flash, google-chrome, firebug

I'm looking for a way to scan a webpage (non-recursive) but it also needs to load the Flash objects.  Because of this, WebClient or HttpWebRequest go out the window.  In my mind, it would have to be done by interfacing with a browser.

Does anyone know of a way that I can interact with Chrome or Firefox to get back network activity on page load programatically?

Edit:  I should clarify that it just needs to load the Flash object, doesn't need to interact with the object.

Comment: Do you need to do this live on your production pages with end users or will an extension work?  Chrome has the debugger extension API which can give you access to all of the network requests - https://developer.chrome.com/debugger.html

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions) on the HTML page:

```
var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
var document = webGet.Load(url);
```

Then walk through the `document` until you find the reference to the Flash object and attempt to download that (either using a WebClient or HttpWebRequest).